# With Vuex, why isn't mapGetters accepting the same syntax as mapState?

Tags: vue.js, vue-component, vuex

I have a Vue component that maps in state, mutations, actions, and getters from a Vuex store.

```
import {mapState, mapMutations, mapActions, mapGetters} from 'vuex'
export default {
  name: 'DefaultLayout',
  computed: {
    ...mapState({
      settings: (state) => state.settings,
      language: (state) => state.language
    }),
    ...mapState([
      'changeRouteTo'
    ]),
    ...mapGetters([
      'isLoggedIn'
    ])
  }
...
```

The problem is, I cannot get `...mapGetters` to work with the explicit syntax like I do with the first instance of `...mapState` above.

I've tried

```
...mapGetters({
  isLoggedIn: (state) => state.getters.isLoggedIn
})
```

and

```
...mapGetters({
  isLoggedIn: (state) => state.isLoggedIn
})
```

and

```
...mapGetters({
  isLoggedIn: (state) => this.$store.getters.isLoggedIn
})
```

But only

```
...mapGetters([
  'isLoggedIn'
])
```

seems to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To use an object in `...mapGetters` the syntax is as follows:

```
...mapGetters({
  isLoggedIn: 'isLoggedIn'
})
```

where the key is the name you want the getter to map to and the value is the name of the getter as a string

Answer (score 1):

with mapGetters you should use getters to access some slice of the state for example in your store you will have something like this

```
const state = {
  isLoggedIn:''
}

const getters = {
  isLoggedIn(state) {
    return state.isLoggedIn
   }
}
export default {
  state,
  getters
}
```

and in your component you can access the isloggedIn property like this

```
 computed: {
      ...mapGetters(['isLoggedIn'])
    },
```

and now you have access to isLoggedIn property 
because mapGetters gives access to the gitters the get functions that returns a slice of the store you dont have to rewrite the get function and pass the state to it that logic you should do it the in the getters this is there purpose

Answer (score 1):

The above answers were all correct, though they don't answer the question "why"?
So the docs don't answer it either - it's a shame.
Let me give you my take:

VueX getters should already do whatever you need.
You see, VueX is meant for large applications. As such, there's a high chance the state or the state that is derived from the base state(getters) will be used in more than one place.

Getters already have access to the VueX state (as they are derived from the state!), they already have access to the other VueX getters too!

I'd say, if you find yourself needing to manipulate the getter, just create another getter that does just that - and simply import it.